# Google App Engine ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-app-engine, azure

I am new to Google App Engine. What i really need to go is host my web service which is written in ASP.net & C# on google app engine.

My web service gets a string and translate that string from already stored translated values in the database which is SQL server 2008 R2. This translated string is in the form of spans. i then return the string.

thanks

Comment: Star this issue... https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11463

Answer (score 3):

The Google App Engine currently supports applications written in Python, Java and Go and won't run ASP.net applications unless some heavy magic (such as compiling it to Java bytecode) is involved and I'm not aware of anything that can do that specific trick.

Maybe you should consider Microsoft's Azure. It's kind of an equivalent PaaS solution, but will play with Microsoft's stack.

Note: Google has since added PHP support.

Note: Now Google has the "custom runtime" that allows you to host pretty much anything you can run on a Linux machine.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I think i will have to convert my web service to any of these languages. Can i connecto SQL server 2008 R2 to python?

Answer (score 2):

It should now be possible to host ASP.NET applications on App Engine. Use the [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes) feature on App Engine and Microsoft's [ASP.NET Docker image](https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker) with your application. Also, you need to create a route for `/_ah/health` and respond with HTTP status code 200 and a blank message body (see [lifecycle events](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes#lifecycle_events)).

Answer (score 1):

You can not host C# applications.

Google App Engine is focused in supporting three application environments only: Java, Python and Go.

Additionally App Engine applications can also be written in any JVM-compatible language (e.g. JRuby, Groovy, Scala, etc.) and run in a Java 6 runtime environment.